# SAP VBA Popup Close

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui, sap-basis

I am doing an extraction in SAP using Excel. But the files are to large, and constantly I get a popup message saying: "EP0:Maximum Hold Time Exceeed". I deal with popups inside SAP very easily, but I don't know how to handle with this type of popup (I think it's generated by the backend, it looks like a Windows popup and the On Error statement is not triggered when it happens). Any idea of how handle this will be very helpfull (:

Comment: Hi! welcome to [so]! The community is happy to help on problems given including a [mcve]! See also [ask]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a SAP error message and not excel.

According to this link :[SAP error question](http://sap.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/sap-basis/maximum-work-process-hold-time-exceeded-379692)

> it's a situation when work process on R/3 server waits for GUI 
>   action. When it exceeds value defined in rdisp/max_hold_time you will get 
>   the message. Otherwise the work process would be blocked. You can try to 
>   alter the parameter - the value is in seconds or install a new GUI

Regarding installing a new GUI ( i think the current one is 730) another user comments that "New GUI may be better optimized in terms of TCP/IP connection."

To alter the timeout parameter you will need access to SM50, SM51 or RZ11 transactions (according to:[Another similar question](https://www.stechies.com/maximun-work-process-hold-time-exceeded/))

It states that to change the parameter:

> Check SM50 or SM51 and see if any users is holding the work process if
>   so kill that processing time then it will be ok 
>   or esle go to RZ11 AND CHECK rdisp/max_wprun_time change it to 300 or
>   600 sec

So basically your program/script needs to wait a little bit longer to successfully complete.

Hope this helps.